# Can we usually skip using intents by using public variables in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

Many times we use intents to send data to a Fragment or get data back from a child. Can't we just put data in a public variable?
For example imagine if we want to get data from user from a dialog box.

I'm just talking about the "possibility". Undoubtedly, It is superior to use intents for code cleanness or safety...

Answer (score 1):

you don't send intent's to fragments, if you want to use objects you need to have your object implement `Parcelable` then you can just send the object in the intent bundle

Comment: @mahyarsefidgaran what you are asking is possible but it breaks how fragments should work. A fragment is suppose to be reusable so if you start hard referencing an activity it is no longer reusable

Answer (score 1):

I think what he means is sending (local)broadcast... which is by the way the proper way of doing it according to my understanding.

Of course it is possible to have public (or even protected) fields and access them from a child-fragment with something like this:

*assuming your parent activity is named "MainActivity"*

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).mMyPublicField
```

or:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).getPublicMethod()
```

**- but I would never recommend doing this!**
especially when you also start manipulating the public field you can run into ugly trouble when different threads are in play.

If something needs so be shared across the whole application, use **SharedPreferences** (if you want to store it for the next app session too) or as I mentioned first **LocalBroadCastManager**.

Comment: Why don;t you recommend it

Comment: wow great! I couldn't ask my question very well. if you have a suggestion to edit my question, so that it would be useful for others, I would welcome that

Comment: It just smells as lack of proper architecture. How will you make sure that no other thread is manipulating the value and you get another value as expected? What about lifecycle of the activity? Can you make sure, that the system will at no point finish() your activity when you are trying to access its public fields?

In the end it is mainly about **loose coupling**. You don't want your Fragment being dependent on a specific activity, no? If you use local broadcasts, you can receive them from any fragment in your activity - and you can send broadcasts to any fragment from your activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public int someValue = 1;
}
```

And in any fragment which has `MyActivity` as a host you can access `((MyActivity) getActivity()).someValue`.

Comment: It is indeed, but it should not be needed in 99% of the cases. It also makes it ugly to read imo.